# Libgdx - touchDown/touchUp vs. Gdx.input.isKeyPressed/Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Here is my dilemma. I am having problems animating my lightning attack by using my GamePad class (I made this class for a game controller for android devices).

I found out that if using the Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(keyname), the code produces a lightning attack every frame, which stack on top of each other. So, I then used the Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed() and it only creates one attack, that is animated, which is perfect.

So when making the GamePad class, I made images with listeners to handle touch events. For each button I have a touchDown and touchUp method. When running my character from left to right, these touch events work fine. However, similar to Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(), the lightning attack is created each frame and the attacks get layered on top of each other. I tried a workaround to fix the creation of an attack each frame, and now the image is just static, and does not animate. This is better than the 60 fps, but doesn't solve my problem.

is there a touchDown event similar to Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed()? How could I fix the GamePad class to work similarly to the Config class?

GamePad.java

```
public class GamePad implements Disposable{

private Viewport viewport;
public Stage stage;
boolean leftPressed, rightPressed, pausePressed, aPressed, bReleased, bPressed, bPreviouslyPressed;
private Config config = Config.getInstance();
private Table table;

public GamePad(){
    viewport = new FitViewport(EIUGame.V_WIDTH, EIUGame.V_HEIGHT, new OrthographicCamera());
    stage = new Stage(viewport);

    table = new Table();
    table.setFillParent(true);
    table.bottom();

    bPreviouslyPressed = false;

    // "Left" Button
    Image leftImg = new Image(new Texture("controller/leftButton.png"));
    leftImg.setSize(35, 35);
    leftImg.addListener(new InputListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
            leftPressed = true;
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
            leftPressed = false;
        }
    });

    // "Right" Button
    Image rightImg = new Image(new Texture("controller/rightButton.png"));
    rightImg.setSize(35, 35);
    rightImg.addListener(new InputListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
            rightPressed = true;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
            rightPressed = false;
        }
    });

    // "Pause" Button
    Image pauseImg = new Image(new Texture("controller/pauseButton.png"));
    pauseImg.setSize(15, 15);
    pauseImg.addListener(new InputListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
            pausePressed = true;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
            pausePressed = false;
        }
    });

    // "A" Button
    Image aImg = new Image(new Texture("controller/aButton.png"));
    aImg.setSize(35, 35);
    aImg.addListener(new InputListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
            aPressed = true;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
            aPressed = false;
        }
    });

    // "B" Button
    Image bImg = new Image(new Texture("controller/bButton.png"));
    bImg.setSize(35, 35);
    bImg.addListener(new InputListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
            bPressed = true;
            setBReleased(false);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
            setBReleased(true);
            bPreviouslyPressed = false;
            bPressed = false;
        }
    });

    table.add(leftImg).size(leftImg.getWidth(), leftImg.getHeight());
    table.add().size(5,35);
    table.add(rightImg).size(rightImg.getWidth(), rightImg.getHeight());
    table.add().size(100, 35);
    table.add(pauseImg).size(pauseImg.getWidth(), pauseImg.getHeight()).bottom();
    table.add().size(100, 35);
    table.add(bImg).size(bImg.getWidth(), bImg.getHeight());
    table.add().size(5,35);
    table.add(aImg).size(aImg.getWidth(), aImg.getHeight());

    stage.addActor(table);
}

// Returns the stage object so that it can be added to a multiplexer
public Stage getStage() {
    return stage;
}

public void draw(){
    stage.draw();
}

public boolean isLeftPressed(){
    return leftPressed;
}

public boolean isRightPressed(){
    return rightPressed;
}

public boolean isPausePressed(){
    return pausePressed;
}

public boolean isAPressed(){
    return aPressed;
}

public boolean isBPressed(){
    return bPressed;
}

public boolean isBPreviouslyPressed(){
    return bPreviouslyPressed;
}

public boolean isBReleased(){
    return bReleased;
}

public void setBReleased(boolean released){
    bReleased = released;
}

public void resize(int width, int height){
    viewport.update(width, height);
}

public void animateChamp(Champion champ, PauseState pause){
    // Move Champion Right
    if (isRightPressed() && champ.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2)
        config.runRight(champ);
    // Move Champion left
    if (isLeftPressed() && champ.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x >= -2)
        config.runLeft(champ);
    // If A button is pressed and we are not jumping or falling, then Jump.
    if (isAPressed() && (champ.getState() != champState.JUMPING && champ.getState() != champState.FALLING)){
        config.jump(champ);
        aPressed = false;
    }
    // Toggle Pause Menu
    if (isPausePressed())
        pause.togglePause();

    // Precondition for next else-if statement
    if (isBPressed() && champ.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x == 0 && champ.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y == 0){
        bPressed = false;
        bPreviouslyPressed = true;
    }
    // If b was pressed down but not released, and champion is not moving, use lightning attack
    else if (bPreviouslyPressed && !isBReleased() && champ.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x == 0 && champ.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y == 0){
        champ.setMobileTrigger(true);        // Sets champion state to attacking region
        config.setMLightningActive(true);
        config.lightningAttack(champ);
    }
    // Exit lightning attack if moved
    else if (!isBReleased() && (champ.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x != 0 || champ.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y != 0)){
        champ.setMobileTrigger(false);
        config.setMLightningActive(false);
        bReleased = true;
    }
    // Exit lightning attack if button released
    else if (isBReleased() && config.getMLightningActive()){
        champ.setMobileTrigger(false);         // Does not alter champion state
        config.setMLightningActive(false);
        bReleased = true;
    }
    // Attack when moving
    else if (isBPressed()){
        config.attack(champ);
        bPressed = false;
    }

}

@Override
public void dispose(){
    stage.dispose();
}
}
```

Config.java

```
public final class Config {
private static final Config instance = new Config();

private int moveLeft;   
private int moveRight;      
private int jump;
private int attack;
private String lStr;
private String rStr;
private String jStr;
private String aStr;
private boolean lightningActive = false;
private boolean MlightningActive = false;   // Mobile Game

// Default constructor sets the keys to a default schema
private Config() {
    moveLeft = Input.Keys.A;    
    moveRight = Input.Keys.D;       
    jump = Input.Keys.L;
    attack = Input.Keys.J;
    lStr = "A";
    rStr = "D";
    jStr = "L";
    aStr = "J";
}

// Return the instance of the class
public static Config getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public void animateChamp(Champion champ){

    // Jump!
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(jump) && (champ.getState() != champState.JUMPING && champ.getState() != champState.FALLING))
        jump(champ);

    // Run Right (and make sure character is not moving faster than 2)
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(moveRight) && champ.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2)
        runRight(champ);

    // Run Left (and make sure character is not moving faster than 2)
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(moveLeft) && champ.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x >= -2)
        runLeft(champ);     

    // Lightning Attack
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(attack) && champ.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x == 0 && champ.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y == 0){
        setLightningActive(true);
        lightningAttack(champ);         
    }
    else if (getlightningActive() && (champ.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x != 0 || champ.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y != 0 || !Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(attack)))
        setLightningActive(false);

    else if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(attack))
        attack(champ);
}

public void runRight(Champion champ){
    champ.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.1f,0), champ.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
}

public void runLeft(Champion champ){
    champ.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-0.1f,0), champ.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
}

public void jump(Champion champ){
    champ.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 4.5f), champ.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
}

public void attack(Champion champ){
    champ.attack();
}

public void lightningAttack(Champion champ){
    champ.lightningAttack();
}

public boolean getlightningActive(){
    return lightningActive;
}

public void setLightningActive(boolean value){
    lightningActive = value;
}

// For Mobile Version
public boolean getMLightningActive(){
    return MlightningActive;
}

// For Mobile Version
public void setMLightningActive(boolean value){
    MlightningActive = value;
}

// sets the key to move left
public void setMoveLeft(String n){
    moveLeft = Input.Keys.valueOf(n.toUpperCase());
    lStr = n;
}

// sets the key to move right
public void setMoveRight(String n) {
    moveRight = Input.Keys.valueOf(n.toUpperCase());
    rStr = n;
}

// sets the key to jump
public void setJump(String n) {
    jump = Input.Keys.valueOf(n.toUpperCase());
    jStr = n;
}

// sets the key to attack
public void setAttack(String n) {
    attack = Input.Keys.valueOf(n.toUpperCase());
    aStr = n;
}

// Returns the string representation of the move left key
public String getMoveLeft(){
    return lStr;
}

// Returns the string representation of the move right key
public String getMoveRight() {
    return rStr;
}

// Returns the string representation of the jump key
public String getJump() {
    return jStr;
}

// Returns the string representation of the attack key
public String getAttack() {
    return aStr;
}

// Returns the int representation of the attack key
public int getAttackInt(){
    return attack;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I might suggest an alternative approach, it sounds like what you really want is to apply a cooldown to your lightning attack- a cooldown keeps it from firing repeatedly if the player holds the button down, and it gives you some control over how fast the player can fire it if they pound the keyboard (you may want to let the player "upgrade" their lightning attack to something faster in the future).

I threw together an example below:

```
public class Cooldown {
    private float cooldownTime = 0;
    private float length = 0;
    private Action action;

    public Cooldown(float length, Action action) {
        this.length = length;
        this.action = action;
    }

    public boolean update(float delta) {
        // Subtract the delta until we hit 0
        this.cooldownTime = this.cooldownTime - delta <= 0 ? 0 : this.cooldownTime - delta;
        // The boolean tells you that the cooldown has expired- useful for special effects
        return this.cooldownTime == 0;
    }

    public void execute() {
        if(this.cooldownTime > 0) return;
        this.cooldownTime = this.length;
        this.action.execute();
    }

    public interface Action {
        void execute();
    }
}
```

To use this class, simply add something like the following somewhere under your player's constructor:

```
this.lighteningAttack = new Cooldown(0.25f, new LightningAttack());
```

Then in your gameloop somewhere:

```
this.lighteningAttack.update(deltaTime);
```

Finally, in your eventlistener:

```
this.lighteningAttack.execute();
```

No matter how many times you press the button, it should only execute four times a second.

Comment: This sounds interesting, I'll give it a try when I find some time. I could also use this approach for my basic attack. Thanks for the reply, i'll get back to you.